# The connectionstring property is not initialized

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio-2013, dotconnect

So, I realize that there are a lot of questions on here pertaining to this problem, but none seem to be the same as to what I'm dealing with. I had to delete my dataset out of visual studio and bring it back in. After doing so I got the error. I'm using mysql as a backend, so I'm using the dotconnect for mysql extension for visual studio. Everything was working fine until I did this step. Here is my app.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="RMSteel.My.MySettings.RMSteelConnectionString" connectionString="User Id=rmsteel;Password=password;Host=192.168.0.46;Database=RMSteel;Persist Security Info=True"
            providerName="Devart.Data.MySql" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>

    </startup>
</configuration>
```

Whenever I use my connection I use the name RMSteel.My.MySettings.RMSteelConnectionString, since this is auto-generated (I assume by dotconnect). I am fairly far in this project and would like to find a fix using this connection string, so I don't have to rewrite that much. Thanks for any help, and if you'd like me to post more code, I can.

Comment: Like I said as well, this connection string was working fine, until I redid my dataset

Comment: Just reading through my files trying to figure this out. Should there be a build option set for the Settings.settings file?

Comment: Trying to work this out, in my first form that loads, this works:

Comment: `MsgBox(RMSteel.My.Settings.RMSteelConnectionString)`

Comment: `Me.EmployeeTableAdapter.Fill(Me.RMSteelDataSet.Employee)` and this doesn't

Comment: So, I narrowed it down to a tableadapter issue. When I comment out the tableadapter.fill the form loads and works correctly (it uses a couple queries to log people in). But when the next form loads that has a table adapter it throws the same error.